# Embedded arm compiler on zynq?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, xilinx, archlinux, zynq

I want to design a Linux-based firmware on Zynq which could support on board compilation of a c program and then execute it. So I need a compiler for arm architecture but then how could I really do it? Is it really feasible to do it or what problems could I face while trying to do it?

I will really grateful if someone can provide me some help here.

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://ellcc.org/blog/?topic=ellcc-on-xilinx-zynq), ELLCC works on a Zynq running pentalinux. It should also run on archlinux. It can be used as a cross compiler also.

Answer (score 1):

Xilinx has a [layer of Yocto](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Yocto) for the Zynq. There are also [pre-built images](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Zynq+2014.4+Release) that can be used to get started with Yocto.

Yocto can provide a native gcc the zynq, so you should be able to get a working compiler.

In my opinion, you are going to face two main problems:

- learning yocto, which is not easy to learm
- dealing with the VHDL to configure the zynq and matching it configuration to the kernel, but this is probably going to be solved by using the pre-built images I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any Linux distribution that supports armv7.
We are currently using a Debian but we tried Arch and Gentoo too.
With a standard Linux distribution you can install whatever compiler toolchain you want.

It is possible to use clang/gcc and visual studio code as IDE over vnc for example so headless coding is possible too.